# Need Help Trying to Code the Right Way to Stop the Buzzer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this script which I am running on my raspberry pi keyboard to use a sensor to measure distance and return certain beeps accordingly.

It works but I have a very strange issue. If the distance is less than 10cm, it will keep beeping  continuously, this is as intended.

I have been using mu IDE and the weird thing is when I press the stop button, it just continues beeping. The only way to stop it is if I run the script again and I make sure that the distance measured is more than 50cm which is as the code intends. This happens on every IDE I tried.

BUT on my terminal, if I make it measure a distance of less than 10cm and press ctrl+c to stop it afterwards, the beeping can stop.

I wonder if it is a issue with the code defining "stop" as keyboard interrupt... Any help is much appreciated :)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
TRIG = 21
ECHO = 20
BUZZER = 26
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(BUZZER, GPIO.OUT)

def measure_distance():
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    print('Waiting 2 secs for the sensor to settle')
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for sensor to settle

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    pulse_start = time.time()
    pulse_end = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
    distance = pulse_duration * 17150
    distance = round(distance, 1)

    return distance

def beep_freq(distance):
    # if dist > 50, no beep
    if distance > 50:
        return -1
    # if dist more than 30 and less than or equal 50, beep once per second
    elif 30 < distance <= 50:
        return 1
    # if dist more than 20 and less than or equal 30, beep twice per second
    elif 20 < distance <= 30:
        return 0.5
    # if dist more than 10 but less than or equal 20, beep 4 times per second
    elif 10 < distance <= 20:
        return 0.25
    # if dist less than 10, beep constantly
    else:
       return 0
       
try:
     while True:
            # Measure distance
        measured_distance = measure_distance()
        print('Distance:', measured_distance, 'cm')

        # get beeping frequency based on the distance
        freq = beep_freq(measured_distance)
        # print freq for debugging
        print('freq', freq)
        # Pause before the next measurement
        time.sleep(1)
        
        # no beeping
        if freq == -1:
            GPIO.output(BUZZER, False)
        # beep once per second
        elif freq == 1:
            GPIO.output(BUZZER, True)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(BUZZER, False)
        # beep twice per second
        elif freq == 0.5:
            for _ in range(2):  
                GPIO.output(BUZZER, True)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                GPIO.output(BUZZER, False)
                time.sleep(0.5)
        # beep four times per second
        elif freq == 0.25:
            for _ in range(4):  
                GPIO.output(BUZZER, True)
                time.sleep(0.25)
                GPIO.output(BUZZER, False)
                time.sleep(0.25)
        # beep constantly
        elif freq == 0:
            GPIO.output(BUZZER, True) 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
          GPIO.output(BUZZER, False)
          GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have tried editing the code with different exit variations but still no luck.